# vim: netrw to skip searching directory

Tags: vim, netrw

When use :Ex to search files under a current project, I would like to search to skip certain directories. The netrm document says that "g:netrm_list_hide" option can be used to achieve this, but my experiments with the options shows it only applies to the filename but not the directory name.

The google search also yields no solution to this. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: I assume you mean `netrw`? I don't know of anything named `netrm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Hiding-Subversion-directories-within-netrw-td1167827.html

To hide directory names just add a trailing slash when you list them. For example to hide the directory `.git/` use the following.

```
let g:netrw_list_hide='^\.git/$'
```